# Getting a warning in every file in a nuxtJs

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs2

I keep getting this `doctor.md` error for every `{filename}.vue` when open in my `nuxtjs` application

**index.vue Doctor**
❗ Incorrect Target
Target version mismatch. You can specify the target version in `vueCompilerOptions.target` in `tsconfig.json / jsconfig.json`. (Expected "target": 2.7)

```
vue version: 2.7.15
tsconfig target: 3 (default)
vue: c:\Users\Tim\Documents\Nuxt\nuxt-app\node_modules\vue\package.json
tsconfig: Not found
vueCompilerOptions:
{
  "extensions": [
    ".vue"
  ]
}
```

**What does it mean ? How to avoid this error ?**